# curl -X PUT zsh permission denied

Tags: rest, curl, express, zsh, mean-stack

Tutorial: https://thinkster.io/angulartutorial/mean-stack-tutorial/#upvoting-posts-10

I've been learning MEAN tutorial through the thinkster link above (emulating Reddit/Hacker News) and I've been perplexed on a permission denial when sending a curl -X PUT command:

`curl -X PUT http://localhost:3000/posts/<POST ID>/upvote`

Response: `zsh: permission denied: /upvote`

I'm expecting the post value returned back with the upvote property incremented.

I've set up my models (Posts and Comments), routes, and schemas to match that of the tutorial and I'm not sure what I'm missing. Is this an issue with permission levels on my end? If so, how do I go about changing it or modifying it for just testing purposes like above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that `<POST ID>` is intended to be replaced by an actual post id (Thanks to [Daniel Stenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93747/daniel-stenberg) for pointing this out). So if the post id would be `123456` the command would look like this:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:3000/posts/123456/upvote
```

If `<POST ID>` is indeed intended to be used in the command verbatim you have to quote the URL:

```
curl -X PUT 'http://localhost:3000/posts/<POST ID>/upvote'
```

**Explanation**:

`>` (as well as `<`) are syntactic elements of `zsh` (and most other unix shells). `>` is used to redirect the output of a command to a file instead of standard output. In this case `zsh` thinks that it should write the output to `/upvote`.

Additionally, there are two more issues with that line. `<POST` is taken as "read input from the file POST". And even if `<` and `>` were not special, there is still a space in `<POST ID>` which would break the URL into two arguments.

So originally the line was interpreted like this:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:3000/posts/ < POST ID > /upvote
---- -- --- ---------------------------- ------ -- ---------
^    ^  ^   ^                            ^      ^  ^ 
|    |  |   |                            |      |  \_ redirect stdout to /upvote
|    |  |   |                            |      \_ 4th argument to curl
|    |  |   |                            \_ read stdin from POST   
|    |  |   \_ 3rd argument to curl
|    |  \_ 2nd argument to curl
|    \_ 1st argument to curl
\_ command
```

Comment: Additionally, I would guess that "<POST ID>" in the URL should be replaced with an actual ID...

Comment: @DanielStenberg Thanks for the tip. I would guess you are quite right with that assumption.

Comment: @DanielStenberg I tried that as well with an actual ID but got the same response. Let me check once more...